# Use a singleton class in kotlin, but call an external function to initialize it?

Tags: kotlin

I want to wrap `Jackson`s `ObjectMapper` class and turn it into a single instance tool class.

But the singleton class has no constructor, I don't know what should I do?

I hope to achieve such a function, see the pseudo code below:

```kotlin
object Jackson: ObjectMapper() = jacksonObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, false)
```

Comment: What does `jacksonObjectMapper()` do? Seems like that is returning your mapper already, so whether it is a singleton or not is already determined. Calling `configure` on it doesn't create a new instance that you can use as a separate singleton class.

Comment: @Tenfour04 `jacksonObjectMapper()` does return an `ObjectMapper`, but is it returning a singleton? Not sure, this is a function provided by the open source library. I haven't looked at the internal source code for `jacksonObjectMapper()`, so I'll have to assume for now that it's not a singleton.

Comment: Can you link to the documentation or source code of this function? Is it part of Jackson or some other library you’re using? There’s nothing to stop you from subclassing ObjectMapper to make your own singleton but I don’t know what this function is doing differently than the constructor.

Comment: @Tenfour04 [document](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin#usage) [source code](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/blob/df8fd64e1bf6a6a293a2d885258631d545a1782d/src/main/kotlin/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/kotlin/Extensions.kt#L38) I don't think it returns a singleton.

Comment: No it doesn’t, and it internally uses factories to create the instance. So there’s no way to create an `object` out of it.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the most straightforward way would be to just wrap the ObjectMapper instance in a named object:

```
object Jackson {
    val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, false)
}
```

And access it with `Jackson.mapper`. I am not aware of a more concise way to create or use a singleton for a java class.

Comment: You could just do `val Jackson =`. Not really proper naming convention, but we we aren't really talking about a singleton anyway.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I haven't learned anything about the JVM, but I'm guessing that `val Jackson =` this way would be it resides in memory for a long time?

Comment: This is really a solution to achieve the demand.

Comment: Any instance assigned to a `val` in an `object` or outside the scope of a class will be kept in memory until your app is terminated. I’m not sure if this is your goal.